# How to get process id from process name?

Tags: macos, bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to create a shell script getting the *process id* of the Skype app on my Mac.

> ps -clx | grep 'Skype' | awk '{print $2}' | head -1

The above is working fine, but there are two problems:

**1)**
The *grep* command would get all process if their name just contains "Skype". How can I ensure that it only get the result, if the process name is exactly *Skype*?

**2)**
I would like to make a shell script from this, which can be used from the terminal but the process name should be an argument of this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ps -clx | grep '$1' | awk '{print $2}' | head -1
```

This isn't returning anything. I think this is because the *$2* in the awk is treated as an argument too. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `ps -cl1` output looks like this:

```
  UID   PID  PPID        F CPU PRI NI       SZ    RSS WCHAN     S             ADDR TTY           TIME CMD
  501   185   172      104   0  31  0  2453272   1728 -      S    ffffff80145c5ec0 ??         0:00.00 httpd
  501   303     1 80004004   0  31  0  2456440   1656 -      Ss   ffffff8015131300 ??         0:11.78 launchd
  501   307   303     4004   0  33  0  2453456   7640 -      S    ffffff8015130a80 ??         0:46.17 distnoted
  501   323   303 40004004   0  33  0  2480640   9156 -      S    ffffff80145c4dc0 ??         0:03.29 UserEventAgent
```

Thus, the last entry in each line is your command. That means you can use the full power of regular expressions to help you.

The `$` in a regular expression means the end of the string, thus, you could use `$` to specify that not only does the output must have `Skype` in it, it must end with `Skype`. This means if you have a command called `Skype Controller`, you won't pull it up:

```bash
ps -clx | grep 'Skype$' | awk '{print $2}' | head -1
```

You can also simplify things by using the `ps -o` format to just pull up the columns you want:

```
ps -eo pid,comm | grep 'Skype$' | awk '{print $1}' | head -1
```

And, you can eliminate `head` by simply using `awk`'s ability to select your line for you. In `awk`, `NR` is your record number. Thus you could do this:

```
ps -eo pid,comm | grep 'Skype$' | awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}'
```

Heck, now that I think of it, we could eliminate the `grep` too:

```
ps -eo pid,comm | awk '/Skype$/  {print $1; exit}'
```

This is using awk's ability to use regular expressions. If the line contains the regular expression, 'Skype$', it will print the first column, then exit

The only problem is that if you had a command `Foo Skype`, this will also pick it up. To eliminate that, you'll have to do a bit more fancy footwork:

```
ps -eo pid,comm | while read pid command
do
    if [[ "$command" = "Skype" ]]
    then
        echo $pid
        break
    fi
done
```

The `while read` is reading two variables. The trick is that `read` uses white space to divide the variables it reads in. However, since there are only two variables, the last one will contain the rest of the entire line. Thus if the command is *Skype Controller*, the entire command will be put into `$command` even though there's a space in it.

Now, we don't have to use a regular expression. We can compare the command with an equality.

This is longer to type in, but you're actually using fewer commands and less piping. Remember `awk` is looping through each line. All you're doing here is making it more explicit. In the end, this is actually much more efficient that what you originally had.

Answer (score 2):

If `pgrep` is available on Mac, you can use `pgrep '^Skype$'`.  This will list the process id of all processes called `Skype`.

You used the wrong quotes in your script:

```
ps -clx | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2}' | head -1
```

or

```
pgrep "^$1$"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second example is that the $1 is in single quotes, which prevents bash from expanding the variable. There is already a utility that accomplishes what you want without manually parsing ps output.

```
pgrep "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd so something like:

```
ps aux | grep Skype | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'
```

==== UPDATE ====

Use the parameter without quotes and use single quotes for `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash
ps aux | grep $1 | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set skypeProcess to the process "Skype"
    set pid to the unix id of skypeProcess
    pid
end tell
```

which means you can use 'osascript' to get the PID from within a shell script:

```
$ osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "set skypeProcess to the process \"Skype\"" -e "set pid to the unix id of skypeProcess" -e "pid" -e "end tell"
3873
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the output of ps using the -o [field],... and list by process name using -C [command_name] ;however, ps will still print the column header,  which can be removed by piping it through grep -v PID

```
ps -o pid -C "$1" |grep -v PID
```

where $1 would be the command name (in this case Skype)

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1 - Use awk

I don't see any reason to use the -l flag (long format), I also don't see any reason to use grep and awk at the same time: awk has grep capability built in. Here is my plan: use ps and output just 2 columns: pid and command, then use awk to pick out what you want:

```
ps -cx -o pid,command | awk '$2 == "Skype" { print $1 }'
```

## Method 2 - Use bash

This method has the advantage that if you already script in bash, you don't even need awk, which save one process. The solution is longer than the other method, but very straight forward.

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -cx -o pid,command | {
    while read pid command
    do
        if [ "_$command" = "_$1" ]
        then
            # Do something with the pid
            echo Found: pid=$pid, command=$command
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pgrep myAwesomeAppName`

This works great under Catalina 10.15.2

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to allow bash to perform variable substitution.
Single quotes disable bash variable substitution mechanism.

```
ps -clx | grep "$1" | awk "{print $2}" | head -1
```