# Getting JAVA PID PHP

Tags: java, php, linux, bash, pid

I am currently hosting a java server program(craftbukkit), and it seems that when I try to get the RAM usage from the server program(craftbukkit), it doesn't return the actual used RAM, but rather somewhere around half of what it's using. (though it's not always exactly half, so it's impossible to estimate actual RAM usage this way).

I was wondering how I might go about getting the actual RAM used by the java process, as seen in the system monitor tool(on linux), this way I would be able to retrieve the amount of RAM used as reported to the system.

I saw an example previously using the PID of the process, but I don't know how to go about getting the PID of the process, knowing only the name.(only one java instance is running, so we don't have to worry about getting the wrong result)

Thanks ahead of time!

With ps -ef | grep "java" I get the following output

```
prodynamics@prodynamics:~$ ps -ef | grep "java"
1000     22292 29385 75 12:08 pts/0    00:42:19 java -Xmx3100M -Xms1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=248m -jar craftbukkit.jar
1000     23544 23443  0 13:04 pts/2    00:00:00 grep java
```

But with  ps -eo pid | grep "java"
The console returns no results at all. Though to my understanding it should return the PID.

Comment: It could be that the program is reporting real memory usage but java allocates/reserves more. I suggest you take a look on how to see how much memory is being used by your OS (I presume Linux) and execute a command in PHP that parses that.

Comment: When I try to get memory usage from inside the program, it returns LESS, than the OS reports allocated, which is not the value I want. I need the value reported by the operating system, what I'm asking is HOW to get what the OS reports as USED, via php, WITHOUT the PID. I'm aware that it's reporting real memory usage, but I need to get allocated memory. That's what I'm asking HOW to do. I know what I need to do, but not how....

Comment: If you know the name, google for "linux get process memory usage" and check what "grep" does...

Comment: I only found results that show using the PID to get memory usage, not the process name. I mean, why in the hell would I google first, it's not as if that would be faster than asking someone for help....*obvious sarcasm should be obvious*

Comment: As said, if you know the name of your program, you can get the PID: ```ps -ef | grep "my program"```

Comment: I'm new to linux and don't understand how to process grep output to find the right process. There's ZERO examples of how to do this, thus why I'm here asking how.

Comment: copy paste what I just put there. ps = process list, the pipe means you pipe it through to another command (like a filter). With grep you only "grab" the "my program" containing lines.

Comment: How do I process the returned data to get only the PID out of it? It returns more than just the PID of the process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415740/how-to-get-process-id-from-process-name

Comment: It's not working..... the command just returns nothing at all.
    ps -eo pid,comm | grep 'java$' | awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}'
    ps -eo pid,comm | awk '/java$/  {print $1; exit}'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to succesfully get the PID with the following

```
ps -eo pid,comm | grep 'java$' | awk '{print $1}' | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, if you really need to get it:

```
ps -ef | grep "java" | grep -v -i "grep" | cut -d ' ' -f 7
```

This will only return the PID of the java process, and will exclude the `grep` call that you make this way. It might need some tweaking of the 7 on the end, depending on your system.

What it does, is take all the results from `ps -ef` and filter to only those containing `java`, but not containing `grep`. Then it cuts the result at every space, and returns field 7 (where the 7 is the number on the end)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to lose your time with `ps`, pipes, `grep` a.o. All you need is `pgrep`:

```
pgrep java
```

See `man pgrep` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also retrieve the PID from your Java application, using the [platform runtime MXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html)'s `getName()` method:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class Pid {
  /**
   * Return the current process ID.
   * @return the pid as an int, or -1 if the pid could not be obtained.
   */
  public static int getPID() {
    int pid = -1;
    // we expect the name to be in '<pid>@hostname' format - this is JVM dependent
    String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    int idx = name.indexOf('@');
    if (idx >= 0) {
      String sub = name.substring(0, idx);
      try {
        pid = Integer.valueOf(sub);
        System.out.println("process name=" + name + ", pid=" + pid);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not parse '" + sub +"' into a valid integer pid :");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return pid;
  }
}
```